# Submit Form using JQuery Ajax and get xml response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form which submits crossdomain but the page will return some XML like this:

```
<response>
<result>12</result>
<message>Invalid parameter.</message>
<error><code>0</code>
<desc>Parameter[first_name] value is empty</desc>
</error>
</response>
```

What JQuery Ajax submit form format do I need to use so I can submit the form and get the result for example I need what's in the  tag.

Comment: can you add you code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally This is the Ajax form submit code that I use.

```
          $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        url: 'url',
        data: $('#your_form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            //whatever
        }
    });
```

In any case if you want make a crossdomain request you have to change your controller to allow it.

```
          public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials";
public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";
public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS = "Access-Control-Request-Headers";
public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD = "Access-Control-Request-Method";
public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS_VALUE = "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS";



       response.addHeader(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, request.getHeader(ORIGIN));
       response.addHeader(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, ALLOW_CREDENTIALS);
```